# Android: setText() for TextView in PopupWindow not working

Tags: android, textview, popupwindow

Basically, I have a TextView in a layout which I use for a PopupWindow.  I show this PopupWindow when a user clicks a button; I want to be able to dynamically change the text in the PopupWindow upon button click.  However, findViewById(my_textview).setText() does not seem to do anything, and indeed causes the PopupWindow to no longer show when I click the button.

I can set text from the layout xml fine.

Anyone know what's up with this?  Thanks-

Comment: Can you post you answer as an answer and accept? That way other people can more easily find the solution if they are having the same question and it keeps the unanswered questions list clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved the problem. For whatever reason you need to call popup.getContentView().findViewById instead of just findViewById (where popup is your PopupWindow object). I wasn't getting a NullPointerException before so I'm not exactly sure why this fixed the issue but it did.

So the code goes something like:

> PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(your layout and params here);
>
> ((TextView)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.my_textview)).setText("hello there");
>
> pw.showAtLocation(your params here);

Comment: For example: ((TextView) popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTextview1)).setText("hello there");

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to find the views with the "findViewById" only using the view you inflated the popupWindow before

like this

```
private View viewPopUp;
private PopupWindow windowPopUp;
//...
//form_popup is the template to the popup
viewPopUp = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.form_popup, null); 
windowPopUp = new PopupWindow(viewPopUp, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
//...
viewPopUp.findViewById(R.id.popupTopTitle);
viewPopUp.findViewById(R.id.popupMiddleMsg);
//...
```